# Android: ListView - state after scroll

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview where I take control of the focus. When I reach the last visible position and click down the listview does not scroll. However, if I touch and scroll the listview then try to navigate the listview using my custom focus control, it works.

My question is what state does android put a listview in when the user touch and scrolls it?

Comment: focused in touch mode.. there is `focusableInTouchMode` attribute of `View`

Comment: @userSeven7s doesn't that just tell the system if the listview is capable of receiving focus in touch mode? I want to know what flag is set after I have scrolled so I can set it manually. Tried using `requestFocused()` but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: I also tried `requestFocusFromTouch()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the problem was, but changing the Activity to a ListActivity solved the issue.